# randomly display only 5 div elements from a list of Div elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

I have a list of 17 div elements, I want to randomly display only 5 div elements from the list. I know just little JavaScript, and the shuffle function doesn't do much, it doesn't get elements(i.e DIV) by class or ID. our maybe I don't know how to insert them.

```
from this 
 <div class="for-group">one</div>
<div class="for-group"> two </div>
<div class="for-group"> three </div>
<div class="for-group"> four </div>
<div class="for-group"> five </div>
<div class="for-group"> six </div>
<div class="for-group"> seven </div>
<div class="for-group"> eight </div>
<div class="for-group"> nine </div>
<div class="for-group"> ten </div>
<div class="for-group"> eleven </div>
<div class="for-group"> twelve </div>
<div class="for-group"> thirteen </div>
<div class="for-group"> fourteen </div>
<div class="for-group"> fifteen </div>
<div class="for-group"> sixteen </div>
<div class="for-group"> seventeen </div>
```

to this

```
<div class="for-group"> seventeen </div>    
<div class="for-group"> thirteen </div>      
<div class="for-group"> eight </div>     
<div class="for-group"> four </div>     
<div class="for-group"> five </div>
```

Comment: Allowing duplicates in your results or not?

Comment: No duplicates please. I want the javascript code to get element either by ID or by classname. Thanks in advance